# Using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ defintion of limits to prove that $\lim_{k \to \infty}1-a^k=1$, where $k$ is restricted to $\mathbb N$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I learned recently that the notion of limits (as taught through the first 10 chapters of Spivak's *Calculus*) can be generalized to functions with various domains. In this post, I want to confirm that my approach to a given proof is legal/valid.

---

> Consider the function $F$ defined as $F: \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$, with the mapping rule $F(k)=1-a^k$, where $|a|\lt1$ . Show that the $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty}F(k)=1$ using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits.

i.e. I want to prove the following:

$$\forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \ \exists M \in \mathbb N \text{ s.t. } \forall k \in \mathbb N \left[ k \gt M \rightarrow \left|\left(1-a^k\right) - 1\right| \lt \varepsilon \right]$$

To do this, I will use the following two lemmas:

\begin{align}
&(\dagger_1) \quad \text{ For any }k\in \mathbb N,\  |a|^k=\left|a^k\right|\\
&(\dagger_2) \quad \text{ For any }n,m\in \mathbb R^+ \text{ where } n \gt m,\ |a|\lt 1 \rightarrow |a|^n\lt |a|^m\\
\end{align}

---

For an arbitrary $\varepsilon$, let $M_{\varepsilon}=\left\lceil\frac{\ln(\varepsilon)}{\ln\left(|a|\right)}\right\rceil$, where $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ denotes the ceiling function. Therefore, $M_\varepsilon \geq \frac{\ln(\varepsilon)}{\ln\left(|a|\right)}$. We will denote $\frac{\ln(\varepsilon)}{\ln\left(|a|\right)}$ as $\alpha$.

Next, $\left |\left(1-a^k\right)-1 \right|=\left|-a^k\right|=\left|a^k\right|=|a|^k \quad (\dagger_1)$.

Because $k \gt M_{\varepsilon} \geq \alpha$, by $\dagger_2$, we have: $|a|^k \lt |a|^{M_{\varepsilon}} \leq |a|^{\alpha}$. Letting $y = |a|^{\alpha}$, the rules of the natural logarithm allow for: $y=|a|^{\alpha} \implies\ln y=\alpha \ln (|a|) \implies \ln y = \ln \varepsilon \implies y = \varepsilon$.

So with $M_{\varepsilon}=\left\lceil\frac{\ln(\varepsilon)}{\ln\left(|a|\right)}\right\rceil$, we have $|a|^k \lt \varepsilon$.

---

I am a little uncertain if the existential claim in the FOL statement needed to be a natural number...though I reckon (maybe) it does not matter. That is to say, is ...$\exists M \in \mathbb N$... correct as written? Or should it have been: ...$\exists M \in \mathbb R$...

Thanks~